# UICollectionView causes autolayout issues with cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I'm using a UICollectionView with the default `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
```

My custom cell is:

```
class CVLegislationCell : UICollectionViewCell {

    let card = CardView() // A view that uses auto layout

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup()
    {
        self.contentView.addSubview(card)
        card.constrain_edges(to: contentView) // convenience function I wrote for auto layout
    }
}
```

For some reason, I get all kinds of auto layout errors and the size comes out wrong. Am I subclassing incorrectly?

Comment: you need to set `layout.estimatedItemSize` to an actual value

Answer (score 0):

When you added the card as a subview you didn't autolayout this with superview. That is with the cell. Just add autolayout programmatically with the cell.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're saying